# Trust after the first 200 milliseconds

Tags: neuroscience, cognition

In the first 200 ms of meeting someone our implicit / System 1 brain makes a number of inferences (based on age, gender, race, voice, smell among others) to determine whether we ‘like’ the other person or not.

Is there any research or study that shows the relationship of this implicit cognition on latter / explicit evaluations of trust?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. I know many prejudge quickly, but can you provide at least one reference to back the 200ms claim? That seems very quick to me.

Comment: My apologies - Amodio 2014 - The neuroscience of prejudice and stereotyping. Evaluations are made in as little as 29 milliseconds (Klatt et al 2016 Looking Bad)